# Spyder cannot find module named 'pandas_datareader'

Tags: python, pandas, module, spyder, datareader

First off I would like to say that I am aware that this question has been asked before, however, none of the other posts have offered a solution that resolves the problem.

I am trying to use pandas-datareader to grab stock prices from the internet. I am using windows with python version 3.6. I first installed pandas-datareader from the console using

`pip install pandas-datareader`.

I then wrote a code which used the line

`import pandas_datareader.data as web`

It came back with the error

`ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pandas_datareader'

I tried to redownload pandas-datareader, just in case it didn't work the first time, but the console came back with "Requirement already satisfied" so that wasn't the problem.
From there I uninstalled pandas-datareader, and reinstalled it with

`pip3 install pandas-datareader`

I still got the same error message.
I was worried that it might have something to do with old versions of python installed on my computer so I deleted all files for python 2.7, but this did not help the issue. I restarted spyder and my computer and this did not help. I tried Jupiter notebook and this did not help either.

Now to take my investigation one step further, I looked in my file folders at the hidden files to see where pandas-datareader could be hiding. When I go to `C:\Users\J.Shepard\Anaconda3\pkgs` and `C:\Users\J.Shepard\Anaconda3\pkgs` I see that pandas-0.23.0-py36h830ac7b_0 is installed but I cannot find anything that looks like pandas-datareader. In fact, when I search for "pandas-datareader" in my file search, I only see 2 text files with one line of code each. I do not know what to make of this discovery but I thought it might be helpful to someone else.

I hope that I have made a good case to prove that I have genuinely tried and failed to solve this problem on my own. Based on the number of other unresolved posts related to this same question, I believe that this is a question that deserves to be asked again.

Comment: How did you install Spyder? Did you use the Anaconda distribution (which is the recommended method)? If so, you're probably best off sticking to `conda` to install further modules, at least until you're familiar with how the other methods work. But if you start by telling us that, we can help with more detail on how to fix it.

Comment: If you use Anaconda, you should **always** try `conda install package` (in this case `conda install pandas-datareader`) before trying to use pip. That's because pip and conda are not entirely compatibel. If that fails, you can use pip, but in a new conda env, because that can break your Anaconda installation. So my advice is for you to use conda and report back.

Comment: Hello, Thank you for your quick answers! Yes, I initially installed Spyder using anaconda. I tried your command 'conda install package' and I got back the error '"conda" is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.'  After looking on some other questions I resolved to uninstall anaconda and reinstall it with the box checked to make a path for anaconda. After doing this I was able to use 'conda install pandas-datareader' and now my code works. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried conda install pandas-datareader in Anaconda Prompt. It was installed and after my computer restarted, pandas-datareader worked in spyder 3.6.